# CakePHP 4 - Accessing attributes from the association of an association

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I want to create a virtual field for an entity using [CakePHP Virtual Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields). Creating the virtual field is working fine, the problem I have is that the virtual field needs to be calculated using the attributes of an entity that is a second level association of the original entity.

`My entity ------> associated entity ------> association of association ------> attributes`

I don't currently have a clue how to go about this. I naively wondered if something like -

`$the_value = $my_entity->associated_entity->associated_associated_entity->attribute`

might work but this is obviously not right.

All the relationships have been set up correctly so the associations exist, it's just how to access them within the entity file I'm struggling with.

Any suggestions gratefully accepted.

Comment: What type of association do you have?

Comment: @Salines Both the associations are belongsTo (many-to-one)

Comment: Why would you think your example is "_obviously not right_"? I mean, sure, you'd use `$this` instead of `$my_entity`, but other than that the property access from inside the entity works exactly the same as from outside the entity.

Comment: @ndm Fair point. I think I wrote that because I tried it and it wasn't working. What I've since discovered is that I need to include a contain() statement in the table declarations for the top-level "My entity". Having done that it all works fine.